# ¿Cómo puedo comparar la hora del sistema android con una hora elegida?

Tags: android

Quiero mandar una notificacion cuando la hora elegida sea igual a la hora seleccionada. Actulizo la hora y la coloco en un TEXVIEW con esto:

```
private void updateDisplay() {
     displayTime.setText(
new StringBuilder().append(pad(pHour)).append(":").append(pad(pMinute)));
}
```

Pero no sé como compararlo con la hora del sistema Android, espero puedan apoyar ya que esto no me deja avanzar. Pensé en una comparación pero solo funciona cada vez que arranco la aplicación, pues es donde me captura la hora actual.

Answer (score 0):

El método `compareTo()` se utiliza para comparar objetos o en el caso de tipos `String` para determinar la cadena más "grande"; no es lo que necesitas para tu problema en particular.

Para comparar 2 fechas Java 8 posee una mejor implementación para trabajar con tipos de dato `Date`.

En concreto tu caso lo podrías trabajar de una manera sencilla y sin recurrir a librerías externas, te propongo lo siguiente:

```
public static boolean evaluarLimite(Date date1, Date date2) {
    boolean correcto = false;
    long diferencia = (Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime())) / 1000;
    long limit = (60 * 1000) / 1000L;//limite de tiempo

    if (diferencia <= limit) {
        correcto= true;
    }
return correcto;
}
```

Indicas que puedes basarte en un tiempo limite (60 segundos en mi ejemplo) si la diferencia de tiempo entre ambas fechas es mayor a tu limite, entonces deberás tomar la decisión o ejecutar el evento que se requiera.

Ajusta el metodo para que mida la unidad que deseas, toma en cuenta que lo que te muestro arriba trabaja en base a segundos (milisecs/1000) = secs.

Comment: muchas gracias. Solo que no puedo convertir lo que tiene StringBuilder a Date :(

Comment: En Java 8 hay un método en el paquete java.time que se llama DateTimeFormatter.parse(charsecuence); que puede ayudarte. Échale un ojo a la API

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta no es del todo clara. Supongo que tienes una hora digamos en un textView, la cual no indicas de dónde es tomada y dices que quieres compararla con la hora del sistema.

En el código que pones me extraña que uses un `StringBuilder` para obtener la hora... Pero bueno eso no es problema. Sólo por decir que hay otras formas más seguras de obtener fechas y horas...

Dado que las cuestiones de hora y fecha del sistema podrían usarse en más de una ocasión, en diferentes partes de la App, yo por lo general uso una clase `Utils` en la que tengo esos métodos que uno suele necesitar con más o menos frecuencia (obtención de la fecha actual, de la hora actual etc).

Veamos por ejemplo el método que obtiene la hora actual del sistema. Dicho método recibe un parámetro `strFormato`, para hacerlo flexible y mostrar la hora en cualquier formato deseado al momento de llamarlo.

### Método en una clase auxiliar

```
public final class Utils {
   /**
     * Método que devuelve la hora del sistema <br />
     *
     * @param strFormato Formato de la hora deseado
     * @return strHora Cadena con la hora formateada.
     */

    public static String getHora(String strFormato) {

        Calendar objCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strFormato);

        String strHora = simpleDateFormat.format(objCalendar.getTime());
        return strHora;

    }
}
```

### Ejemplo de uso, donde quieres comparar la hora

```
    String strHoraTuya="11:40";
    String strHoraSistema=Utils.getHora("HH:mm"); //Obtenida con el método
```

Luego para comparar, lo harías como se comparan dos cadenas:

```
if (strHoraTuya.equals(strHoraSistema))
{

//iguales

}else{

//diferentes

}
```

Esta comparación la lanzarías desde la acción donde decidas comparar la hora data y la hora actual del sistema: el click de un botón, el inicio de una actividad, etc.